# How to generate crypto.createCipheriv arguments from static source

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, encoding, cryptography

I am using the below code to encrypt strings in my node.js code.

I would like to understand how to generate `KEY` and `HMAC_KEY` from a static source. In my program, it's generated randomly as of now. As it's generated randomly, I am not able to encrypt my database password using the below algorithm.

```
crypto = require('crypto');

ALGORITHM = "AES-256-CBC"; 
HMAC_ALGORITHM = "SHA256"; 
KEY = crypto.randomBytes(32);
HMAC_KEY = crypto.randomBytes(32);

function (plain_text) {    
    var IV = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16)); // ensure that the IV (initialization vector) is random   
    var cipher_text;
    var hmac;
    var encryptor;

    encryptor = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGORITHM, KEY, IV);
    encryptor.setEncoding('hex');
    encryptor.write(plain_text);
    encryptor.end();

    cipher_text = encryptor.read();

    hmac = crypto.createHmac(HMAC_ALGORITHM, HMAC_KEY);
    hmac.update(cipher_text);
    hmac.update(IV.toString('hex')); // ensure that both the IV and the cipher-text is protected by the HMAC

    // The IV isn't a secret so it can be stored along side everything else
    return cipher_text + "$" + IV.toString('hex') + "$" + hmac.digest('hex')

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to split your code into two executions:

1. Code that generates your keys and presents them in a storable format

   ```
   KEY = crypto.randomBytes(32);
   HMAC_KEY = crypto.randomBytes(32);
   console.log(KEY.toString('hex'));
   console.log(HMAC_KEY.toString('hex'));
   ```
2. Code that uses the stored keys

   ```
   KEY = Buffer.from('some key string', 'hex');
   HMAC_KEY = Buffer.from('some other key string', 'hex');
   ```

You just have to make sure that your keys aren't actually in your code, but rather in some file, because hardcoding key in code and checking them into your version control system is a bad idea and might give your developers access to production systems which they probably shouldn't have.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatly i get an error 'Error: Invalid key length' after using KEY = Buffer.from('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef', 'hex'); as suggested by you.Where am i going wrong?could you please guide me.

Comment: It started working after changing KEY = Buffer.from('some key string', 'hex'); to KEY = Buffer.from('some key string', 'binary');

Comment: You should use the same key strings that were shown in step 1